# How to remove shadow from bootstrap menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/31/

```
Code code code
```

Here's the effect I'm trying to correct (note the vertical duplication, which I think is a shadow):

[image]

How can I remove this shadow?  It's happening in chrome and firefox for me - the fiddle shows a gray shadow instead of white.  You may also have to drag the fiddle bar over to the left to show the "Intro" text - bootstrap's responsive menu seems to be kicking in if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following fixed it:

```
#menu-bar p, #menu-bar a {
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```